# Why was my answer suddenly "deleted by owner"?

Tags: support, status-completed

I have posted an answer for the following post
[Is there a way to block USSD balance notifications on Android 4.3?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51875/is-there-a-way-to-block-ussd-balance-notifications-on-android-4-3)

Today when I rechecked the answer it is deleted and shown as "deleted by owner". What does it mean? In the answer I linked an google play app. Thank you.

**UPDATED**

This is getting weird now I looked the post again to check the date and I got this

[image: Check the date]

Comment: From what I can tell, it appears that you deleted it yourself. Did you accidentally delete it?

Comment: @BryanDenny  Thats weird No i didnt delete it

Comment: Now it is there I dont know what really happened

Comment: I undeleted it for you, since it seems you didn't want it deleted :)

Comment: What really happened? Who deleted it in first place?

Comment: The system says that you deleted it. Mar 4 at 14:14 deleted by user3275057

Comment: Mis-clicking most likely.

Comment: But what about the date. Check the date in the image. It was different